# Working with NLP tags in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

Working on a large data-oriented search product powered by elasticsearch. We've built a lot of machine learning functionality on top of this app, but currently we're having some difficulty deciding how to integrate fairly standard NLP-based word tags into our ES index.

Currently we have a tagging service that can annotate a word with a respective type (or types, but one may be useful enough for now). This function could be abstracted to: `type = getWordType(word)` I imagine there must be a way to integrate this tagging service into the analysis chain that is applied at index time, where, maybe, we tell the index what type a particular word belongs to. However, doing this kind of advanced analysis is a bit beyond my elasticsearch capacity. Does anyone have pointers on this kind of advanced analysis in elasticsearch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you might want to take a look at the [ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/ingest.html) functionality introduced in Elasticsearch 5.0. This allows you to preprocess your documents and add fields into the JSON before the document is being indexed in Elasticsearch.

I wrote an ingest processor that is using OpenNLP to enrich documents. You could take a look at that one and adapt it to your needs (also, pull requests are very welcome).

Check it out at https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp

Comment: this is approximately what we were doing, providing supplementary data through secondary, stand-alone processes. I like your approach better, however, the downside to both, that I'm trying to work around here, is that types are provided through secondary fields rather than markup on the original input. Maybe this is fine for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved in Elasticsearch 6.5 with the type `annotated_text`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.x/mapper-annotated-text-usage.html

Essentially, kind of like synonyms, the tags (or named entity IDs, etc) can exist at the same position as the word you’re tagging.

Needs a plugin installed, the Mapper Annotated Text Plugin.